# jsp - Post request with unicode (hebrew letters) not showing correctly

Tags: java, jsp, unicode, hebrew

I'm trying to use jsp to pass a form using post where it's data is filled with hebrew letters.

I don't know how to fix it. I just want the text to show up normally. My code: (The code is in a jsp file called newgame.jsp)

```
<form id="creategame" action="newgame.jsp" method="post">
    //Form containing a bunch of inputs which can have hebrew outputs
</form>
```

My recieving of the input:

```
<%
if(request.getParameter("gamename")!=null){
    String gameName = (String)request.getParameter("gamename");
    String minKita = (String)request.getParameter("minkita");
    String maxKita = (String)request.getParameter("maxkita");
    String gameDesc = (String)request.getParameter("gamedesc");
    String gameZiood = (String)request.getParameter("gameziood");
    System.out.println(gameName+" - "+minKita+" - "+maxKita+" - "+gameDesc+" - "+gameZiood);
    //Upload it to the database...
    response.sendRedirect("gamesdb.jsp");
}
%>
```

Basically:

> `אבגדהוזחטיכלמנסעפצקרשת` turns into `??????????????????????` in the console and `àáâãäåæçèéëìîðñòôö÷øùú` in the database/website. *But, after printing the character data in the console of the "question marks" I can see it's actually `àáâãäåæçèéëìîðñòôö÷øùú` and not just a bunch of question marks.*

So how would I pass the data in my post request so it would stay as the original text?

Thanks in advance, NonameSL.

---

**EDIT:** I am using encoding `windows-1255` which I know that is displaying hebrew letters correctly.

---

**EDIT 2:** I tried to use the following:

```
public String toHebrewString(Object o){
        try{
            return new String(((byte[])o), "UTF-8");
        }catch(Exception unexpected){
            return (String)o;
        }
    }
```

That showed up the exact same result. Could the problem be in my form?

Comment: What if instead of `(String)...` you do `new String((byte[])request..., "UTF-8);`?

Comment: Take a short string of say one letter. Dump its char(s) as integer (hex) value. And work from there the entire trajectory. If you are using UTF-8 for the page and the form data correctly, the console might wrongly convert the String (Unicode internally) to Latin-1, and represent unconvertible chars as question marks console is irrelevant, dump in hexadecimal for info. The same checking for the database.

Comment: What kind of encoding your jsp files uses? Tomcat, and  other application servers will use an encoding based on the underlying platform (static servlet will use this default encoding but you can change that in your own servlet or in Tomcat's web.xml file (which the default servlet uses))

Comment: @JoopEggen Well I tried getting the information in hebrew from the post request and printing the char information as decimal, and for example for the letter `א` it shows 224 which is the character `à` and not the original character. Could it be that something is wrong with my form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that the String `"א"` contains a char with integer value 224, the following went wrong:

- The Hebrew single-byte encoding on Windows is **Windows-1255** and there `(byte)224` is `א`.
- As String/char should hold text in Unicode, the conversion of bytes to String went wrong.
- Check:

  ```
  request.setCharacterEncoding("Windows-1255"); // Once at request begin
  String gameName = request.getParameter("gamename");
  ...
  ```

  This however you would not like to repeat for every returned form being handled.
- Solution: if this is a pure Hebrew site, you might use Windows-1255, but full Unicode with encoding **UTF-8** is more usual. How to present HTML with forms in UTF-8, accept UTF-8 from form data returning and so on, can be found in the internet.

The response encoding is concerned too. As is the database and so on.

Comment: Thank you! I did put the character encoding ontop of the page, but for some reason when I put the request.setCharacterEncoding() method it worked. Also, my site is 99% pure hebrew, but I am changing it into UTF-8 (just to make sure it displays everything correctly), thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Can be configiured grlobally in the server too (depending which one). `<form accept-charset=...>` prevents receiving `&#1234;` from the form.